# Select Dynamic column names from concatenated strings

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a few columns that was built in like this:

```
|  FOOD_AUS  | FOOD_JAP | FOOD_KOR | FOOD_CAN |
```

Is there a way to select it dynamically? I mean like for example if the user will only enter the text `AUS` all the rows under `FOOD_AUS` will return.

Comment: You really need to change your table design.

Comment: Are you using a scripting language along with it (ie PHP)? Or is this strictly MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

It is doable, but not in a single sql call. What you can do is to query [information_schema.columns view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) for matching column names from a table and then create an sql statement using the results in a string variable and execute it via [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

I would do sg along the following lines:

```
select @c:=group_concat(column_name) as col_names
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name='yourtable' and column_name like '%aus%'
    group by table_name;
set @sql:=concat('select ',@c, ' from yourtable');
prepare stmnt1 from @sql;
execute stmnt1;
deallocate prepare stmnt1;
```